# How to delete data from Redis after 48 hours?

Tags: php, arrays, redis, cron

Here I'm saving data in Redis with PHP. I have a Cron to get some data with time.This Cron will run at every 5 minutes. Here I'm using `hSet` to store data.

```
$datetime = date("H.i");

$redisforhttp2->hSet(MACHINE.':count',$datetime,$count);
```

so I will get data like this

```
 [
    "13.25": "64",
    "14.50": "96",
    "14.52": "65",
    "14.54": "39",
    "14.55": "48",
    "14.56": "68",
    "15.03": "66",
    "15.05": "61",
    "15.07": "60",
    "15.10": "41",
    "15.11": "72",
    "15.14": "53"
  ]
```

After two days or some days, it will have a giant bulk of data. so i want to delete data from redis after 48 hours.

```
if(strtotime($dateFromDatabase." + 48 hours") <= strtotime("now"))
{
  //Deleting data from Redis.
}
```

So I thought `hDel` is good for this. But here, the hashKey is dynamic(time). Which is the robust solution for this case? Please suggest me.

> UPDATE

This `$datetime` for creating the dynamic graph.
And here the count is `HTTP count`.

Comment: Why don't you set a timeout on the key when you store the data, let redis delete it automatically for you: `$redisforhttp2->expire(MACHINE.':count', $expireTime);`

Comment: it is for generating graph.

Comment: Why don't you set it to expire after 48 hours?

Comment: how can i use it? but here i'm using `hset`. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to compromise on your data structure a bit. Instead of having a same hash name create dynamic hashes starting with date. For example 2016-05-21_MACHINE.':count' will be your key for today, tomorrow it will be 2016-05-22_MACHINE.':count'. You can run a crontab for every day to delete hashes which are old.

If you think it will generate too much of data before deleting try something like this timestamp/(1000*60*60) will give you a unique hour value irrespective of the date. append it with your key. And run a crontab for every hour which will delete hashes greater than 48 hours.

Also you need to handle areas where you have hget and hgetall.